# Div alignment Issue in FireFox and Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, html, cross-browser

I am using `Div` in my website to display some links. It works fine in IE, but when i expand that `div` in firefox and google chrome it goes weird.

Can anybody help me to figure it out. I have googled it but i did not fine any useful solutions.

```
<td vAlign="top" align="center"><font>-</font></td>
<td align="left"  >
 <div align="left"  style="margin:0 auto; padding:0; display:block;clear:both; position:relative;">
  <A class="inkblue" href="javascript:expand(4);">Faculty &amp; Staff</A
 </div>
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="e4" style="DISPLAY: none">
<td></td>
```

This is the code for that section. Please let me know if anything required.

[This is the link to site](http://www.nu.edu.pk). open it in firefox or chrome and click the link 
"Faculty & Staff" under "Campuses" .

Comment: Your `A` tag is not closing - maybe it's just copy & paste error? Opening `tr` tag is missing as well.

Comment: Yes its copy paste error but in code its correct.

Comment: Can you make a working example on jsfiddle pls?

Comment: I did not understand your point can you clarify please

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your site:

I saw that you are using below line double time. Insert this line only one time.
If your are trying to Override some classes then specify different css file name.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nuonline.css">
```

To overcome your issue:

Currently on click of "**Faculty**, **Events** & **Campus**", you are doing `style="display:inline"`. Rather than doing this way you can remove style attribute itself.

Example:

*On click:* Remove style attribute `style="display:none"` for **id="e4"** or **id="e5"** or **id="e7"**

*To Reset (that is on next click):* Add style attribute as `style="display:none"` for **id="e4"** or **id="e5"** or **id="e7"**

Comment: I made the changes as per your instruction It works for fine but it is expanded already before click. After the mouse click it agains wiered. Can you check i have uploaded with the changes. It also has effect in IE. Div is expanded it should not behave like that.

Comment: @khan: It seems you are removing style attribute for **e4** onload itself. By default make it **e4** as **style="display:none;"**, when user clicks only you need to remove style attribute and also If user clicks once again on the "Faculty" then you need to add style attribute as **style="display:none;"** for **e4**

Comment: This the code please tell me where to set the style attribute. I have remove style=display:inline in javascript for id e4,e5 or e7<tr><td vAlign="top" align="left"><font>-</font></td><td align="left"  ><div align="left"  style="margin:0 auto; padding:0;clear:both; position:relative;"><A class="inkblue" href="javascript:expand(4);">Faculty &amp; Staff</A></div></td>
<td></td></tr><tr id="e4"><td></td><td ><table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"><tr><td class="paragraph" width="10">-</td><td align="left"><A class="inkblue" href="staffhq.aspx">Headquarter</A></td>

Comment: Issue has been resolved. I was using style="Display:inline" but by removing inline now style="display:''" its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

There is one blank `<td></td>` remove it and give `colspan="2"` to next `td` element